# Doc Type Definition: A Syntax Question

Tags: html, xhtml, standards, dtd, web-standards

In the top of my webpages it days:

`<!doctype html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

lang="nl" xml:lang="nl">`

Q1:
Which one is more fault-proof/better in your opinion: `<!doctype html>` or `<!doctype html/>`

Q2:
I wonder whether there is anything shorter than this, which will define the language:
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de" xml:lang="de">`

And should that be ending with `>` of `/>`?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: This is very simple: `<!doctype html/>` is wrong. The doctype is not a self-closing tag, neither in HTML nor in XML. The only valid declaration for HTML5 is therefore `<!doctype html>`.

Q2: That depends. You don’t actually need to declare the XML namespace if you’re using HTML rather than the XHTML variant (and the `xml:lang` attribute would also be pointless). In that case, the doctype (see Q1) is entirely sufficient:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    …
</html>
```

On the other hand, if you want to use XHTML then you should add the XML namespace (and, yes, the `xml:lang` attribute). Using XHTML *does* have advantages, primarily because some editors/evaluators will treat errors stricter and can thus provide better diagnostics for errors.

Comment: Likewise, if you're not using XML, then having the additional namespaced xml:lang attribute is pointless.

Comment: @David: That goes without saying. Or perhaps not. ;-) I’ll add it.

Comment: I wouldn't call the document language an added bonus. Making sure that screen readers get the right pronunciation database and that search engines file the document under the right language is a basic essential in my book. It is just the `xml:` variant that is pointless.

Comment: +1 very clear! Thanks all! Updated the question, see the '>' or '/>' on the second part pelase.

Comment: `<html lang="de">`, and no, only elements with no content can have a `/` and that is useless, optional syntactic sugar if you are writing HTML (rather than XML).

Comment: @David Hm, I actually have to agree. Don’t know why I left it off.